# Android: Using ViewPager to swipe whole TabActivity

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using TabManager to implement with Fragments a screen with tabs as described [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html). That screen displays information about a concrete object in a list. I'd like to swipe the whole screen so as to change the object being used.

I've managed to use ViewPager inside one of the Fragments and got it working, but I'd like to swipe the tabs above too. I've tried to instantiate the ViewPager in the Activity using TabManager and creating a pager adapter which referenced the root view (TabHost) and returning it everytime ViewPager asked for a view, but it didn't work.

Thank you very much in advance.

**EDIT** Here's the code of the class which hosts the tabs and the ViewPager:

```
public class FeederActivity extends RoboFragmentActivity implements OnPageChangeListener {

    @Inject FeederActivityPagerAdapter adapter;
    @InjectView(R.id.details) ViewPager viewPager;

    TabHost tabHost;
    TabManager tabManager;

    // Inside onCreate
    tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();
    tabManager = new TabManager(this, tabHost, R.id.realtabcontent);

    tabManager.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("state").setIndicator(getString(R.string.state)), StateFragment.class, null);
    tabManager.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("programming").setIndicator(getString(R.string.programming)), ProgrammingFragment.class, null);
    tabManager.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("plot").setIndicator(getString(R.string.plot)), PlotFragment.class, null);
    this.viewPager.setAdapter(this.adapter);
    this.viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}
```

[Here](http://tinypic.com/r/fk3z8g/5) is a screenshot of what I have by now.

It displays information of Feeder 6. I'd like to swipe the whole screen (including the tabs State, Programming and Plot) so as to be in Feeder 7.

Comment: So you are using a ViewPager inside a TabHost, am I correct in that assumption?

Comment: I'm using a ViewPager inside a FragmentActivity. That activity uses both TabManager and TabHost. I'll edit my post so as to include some code.

Comment: Cool, if possible post a screenshot as well

Comment: How do you want to navigate the tabs? I believe when you swipe the screen, it will go to the next page in the ViewPager?

Comment: I want to navigate between tabs just by clicking them. When I swipe I want to stay on the same tab which is selected (in the screenshot, State) but having a "sliding effect" which also involves the tab names. ViewPager will provide that effect and get another view when I swipe. This view will be the same as the current, only that internally the current Feeder information will be updated and so the  different TextViews on the screen.